# Extend Jquery in Typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, definitelytyped

I am creating a plugin using Typescript which creates a DOM for Header and attach that to the page. This project uses JQuery for DOM operations. I want to pass config Options to the plugin from the HTML page. For that, I am extending JQuery with my custom function and passing the options in it.

But the problem is when I load that HTML page, I get an error: "$(...).createCentralHeader is not a function".

Here is my Index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body class="siteheader-body">
    <div class="cep-Header"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./dist/cep_HeaderCore.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('cep-Header').createCentralHeader({
            headerUrl: "Hello World!!"
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my main.ts file:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";

$.fn.createCentralHeader = function(this: JQuery, options?: HeaderOptions) {
    const settings: HeaderOptions = {
        headerUrl: options.headerUrl
    };
    alert(settings.headerUrl);
};
```

Here is my central-header.d.ts :

```
interface HeaderOptions {
    headerUrl?: string;
}

interface JQuery {
    createCentralHeader(options?: HeaderOptions);
}
```

I am using webpack which uses ts-loader to transpile TS and bundle my plugin into a file cep_HeaderCore.js that is referenced in index.html.

One more important thing to note here is that if I invoke createCentralHeader from within the plugin, it works as expected. eg:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";

$.fn.createCentralHeader = function(this: JQuery, options?: HeaderOptions) {
    const settings: HeaderOptions = {
        headerUrl: options.headerUrl
    };
    alert(settings.headerUrl);
};

$("cep-Header").createCentralHeader({
    headerUrl: "Hello World!!"
});
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to angular.json

```
"scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
        ]
```

and jquery is extended in main.ts file with next code

```
window['$'].fn.test = function (message: string) {
  alert(message);
};
```

or with extending Windows interface without using property in quotes

Comment: I cannot do that since my invocation happens from <script> in html page where typecasting can't be performed. As I said before, It works from with the plugin but just not from the html.

Comment: I added example from fiddle

Comment: In your example you are calling createCentralHeader() from typescript file. I want to do that from <script> inside HTML file like this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hjo8yvbn/)

Comment: you was right it is a bit tricky  extending browser version of Jquery but adjusting version should work now

Comment: Also keeps in mind that imported in TypeScript jquery module it is not the same that browser version of jquery

Comment: Dude, it worked when I added that function in the window object. It did not strike me that the jQuery version in plugin and HTML are different.